# How to reposit of the tabBox's title?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I'm struggling to reposition the dashboardBody cause as I show in the picture attached, it's cutting part of tabBox's title. I tried to use `side = "right"`, also `tags$style(HTML(".tab-content{width:300px}"))` and changing the `width = "n values"` but it doesn't take any alterations. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I really appreciate!

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title="Deteccao de arvores individuais de LiDAR em Shiny App - R", titleWidth = 800),
  dashboardSidebar(tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar{width: 300px;}")),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Defina seus parametros e preferencias", icon =icon("dashboard"))),
    conditionalPanel( 
       fileInput('layer', 'Select the CHM.asc file', multiple=FALSE, accept='asc', width = "350px"),
       selectInput("fws", "Select the size of windows to find trees", choices = c("3x3"= (fws<-3), "5x5"= (fws<-5), "7x7"= (fws<-7)), width = "350px"),
       checkboxInput("checkbox", "Would you like to apply the smoothing model for canopy?", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), selectInput("sws", "Select the size of the smoothing window for trees", choices = c("3x3" = (sws<-3), "5x5" = (sws<-5), "7x7"=(sws<-7)), width = "350px"),
       checkboxInput("checkp", "Plot individual trees detected in CHM", value=FALSE, width="350px"),
       checkboxInput("checkpd", "Download the shapefile (.shp) of Individual trees detected", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), uiOutput("shapefile"),
       actionButton("action", "RUN!"))

      ),

  dashboardBody( 
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(title= tagList(shiny::icon("cogs"), "Results"), width = "200px", height = "600px", side = "right",
                tabPanel("Visualization of CHM", plotOutput("mapPlot")),
                tabPanel("Trees detected from rLiDAR", tableOutput("arvlist"), downloadButton("downList", "Download Tree List")),
                tabPanel("Summary of LiDAR metrics", tableOutput("sumy"), downloadButton("downSumy", "Download Summary of LiDAR metrics")),
                tabPanel("Profile of height model", plotOutput("hist"), downloadButton("downHist", "Download Height's Histogram of Density")), #histograma de densidade
                tabPanel("Individual trees detected - Model 2D of CHM", plotOutput("plotTrees"), downloadButton("downDetec", "Download CHM of Trees Detected"))


                 )


    ))
  )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHuyv.png)

Comment: Try decreasing the width of the `tabBox`. It looks like the width of your `tabBox` is too large to fit in the dashboard body.

Comment: Hey @SBista! I tried to do that, but it seems that for some reason that I don't know, the width doesn't change in the App, even when I'm modifying the values in the ui.R. Do you know why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the width does the trick

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title="Deteccao de arvores individuais de LiDAR em Shiny App - R", titleWidth = 800),
  dashboardSidebar(tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar{width: 200px;}")),
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("Defina seus parametros e preferencias", icon =icon("dashboard"))),
                   conditionalPanel( 
                     fileInput('layer', 'Select the CHM.asc file', multiple=FALSE, accept='asc', width = "350px"),
                     selectInput("fws", "Select the size of windows to find trees", choices = c("3x3"= (fws<-3), "5x5"= (fws<-5), "7x7"= (fws<-7)), width = "350px"),
                     checkboxInput("checkbox", "Would you like to apply the smoothing model for canopy?", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), selectInput("sws", "Select the size of the smoothing window for trees", choices = c("3x3" = (sws<-3), "5x5" = (sws<-5), "7x7"=(sws<-7)), width = "350px"),
                     checkboxInput("checkp", "Plot individual trees detected in CHM", value=FALSE, width="350px"),
                     checkboxInput("checkpd", "Download the shapefile (.shp) of Individual trees detected", value = FALSE, width = "350px"), uiOutput("shapefile"),
                     actionButton("action", "RUN!"))

  ),

  dashboardBody( 
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(title= tagList(shiny::icon("cogs"), "Results"), width = "500px", height = "600px", side = "right",
             tabPanel("Visualization of CHM", plotOutput("mapPlot")),
             tabPanel("Trees detected from rLiDAR", tableOutput("arvlist"), downloadButton("downList", "Download Tree List")),
             tabPanel("Summary of LiDAR metrics", tableOutput("sumy"), downloadButton("downSumy", "Download Summary of LiDAR metrics")),
             tabPanel("Profile of height model", plotOutput("hist"), downloadButton("downHist", "Download Height's Histogram of Density")), #histograma de densidade
             tabPanel("Individual trees detected - Model 2D of CHM", plotOutput("plotTrees"), downloadButton("downDetec", "Download CHM of Trees Detected"))


      )


    ))
)
```

Hope it helps!